# Why does the liberty-gradle-plugin fail on CompileJSP?

Tags: gradle, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, java-ee-8

I am trying to get the `liberty-gradle-plugin` to run. I created a minimal `build.gradle` and it still fails:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.openliberty.tools.gradle.Liberty' version '3.0'
    id 'war'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0.1'

    libertyRuntime group: 'com.ibm.websphere.appserver.runtime', name: 'openliberty-runtime', version: '[20.0.0.2,)'
}
```

It fails with:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.openliberty.tools.gradle.Liberty', version: '3.0']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.openliberty.tools.gradle.Liberty']
   > Could not create task ':compileJSP'.
      > Could not create task of type 'CompileJSPTask'.
         > Could not generate a decorated class for class io.openliberty.tools.gradle.tasks.CompileJSPTask.
            > io/openliberty/tools/ant/ServerTask
```

I have no intention to use JSP. So is there a way to fix this? Or to disbale the JSP part?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a bug: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.gradle/issues/441
The using the buildscript version works for now.